# MathCAD 2001 формула Монте Карло для решения интегралов

Tags: интегральное-исчисление, mathcad, монте-карло

У меня есть проблема с решение интеграла через формулу Монте-Карло
Я изучил весь форум и интернет, но так и не смог найти, как решить второй интеграл через метод Монте-Карло, именно в моей версии MathCAD и потом написать ещё туже формулу но через блок MathCAD. У всех версии новее. Если кто-то знает, как правильно описать это в MathCAD, поделитесь, пожалуйста.
Я был бы рад поставить новую версию MathCAD, что бы подключить необходимые функции, но моему прподователю это неподходит, я ему уже говорил про это, но он не хочет ставить новые версии, ибо не хочет платить за это или скачивать торенты. По этому такая ситуация и сложилась((
[image: Cам интеграл, нижняя граница, верхняя граница, количество иттераций, и шаг интегрирования]